# wxPython: How to update window size as the window resizes in real-time

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I would like to be able to obtain the window size of an app and pass it to other modules in an application, and when the window size updates (say, if a user resizes the window), the updated window size also gets passed to other modules.

For example, I tried something like the code below where I tried to store the window size in `self.size` so that it could be used in `foo()`. However, this code would give me an error message saying `'TestPanel' object has no attribute 'size`. I wonder if there is a way to do what I want to accomplish.

```
import wx
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize, self)
        self.foo()

    def Resize(self):
        self.size = self.GetSize()

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.Resize()

    def foo(self):
        print(self.size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    f = wx.Frame(None, -1)
    TestPanel(f)
    f.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first find out what gave you that error message in the first place.  With your code as is, do realize that in the `__init__` method, the `size` attribute was not set anywhere before its `foo` was called, giving you that error.

What you want to do is to delay the calling of `foo` to your handler for `EVT_SIZE`, in this case `OnSize`.  The event will be called when the window becomes visible as it will be resized to the default size (thus setting `self.size`).  You could then simplify what you want to do to:

```
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize, self)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.size = self.GetSize()
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        print(self.size)
```

Override `foo` to call into the other window, or whatever.